# can't view string fields in an hdf5 file

Tags: hdf5

A python program (https://github.com/MannLabs/alphapeptdeep) created the following hdf5 file--> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ct2B7IU2WsqJfT3eGoR1xn3GSOffFqtN/view?usp=sharing

I can *successfully* open it up in HDFView, view metadata, and even view the data for floating point value fields.

However, for string fields, it simply gives an error (which I suspect is misleading).

For example, if one tries to view the data for this field:

`/library/mod_seq_df/sequence`

It gives the following (misleading?) error:

`failed to read scalar dataset: Filter not available exception: Read Failed`

I installed HDFView 3.1.4 on a clean debian 11 docker container. And I installed the HDF5 filter plugins as well from HDF5-1.14.0 installation scripts.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you use any compression filters when you created the file?

Comment: So, I didn't create the file so I don't know how it was created. That said, when I look at the file through HDFView, it *is* able to show me the field metadata, and so if I'm interpreting it correctly,all the fields (both float and string) were compressed, but I have no trouble with the float fields, just the string ones....

Comment: Are the floats and strings in different datasets? Or are they different fields in a compound (heterogeneous) dataset? The only time I have seen this is when I used a  compression algorithm that was not included in The HDF Group library (specifically, zstd).

Comment: different datasets (if I'm using hdf5 terminology correctly). However, I think the compression algorithm used (based on the hdfview metadata information) was the same

Comment: Although not being able to view the data in HDFView is inconvenient, it's not a show stopper. You should be able to access the data with `h5py` or `pytables`. And, you should also be able to use the `h5dump` utility to dump data.

Comment: So, I actually need to access the data via Java, but my own Java code had the same issue as HDFView....so it seem like an issue either in C or Java API?

Comment: Hmmm.... interesting. I'm running out of ideas. My best guess is 3rd party compression library that you haven't installed. I am away from my computer until Friday, but can investigate when I get back.

Comment: That's be super helpful, @kcw78 ...it's been driving me nuts!

Comment: I'm making some progress. Based on datasets names, I'm 99.44% sure this file was created by exporting Pandas dataframes. (`name_df` is the give-away.) So, I opened the file with Pandas 1.2.4. I can create an HDFStore, but get this error message for multiple datasets when I interrogate it: `variable length strings are not supported yet`. I suspect these are the same datasets that are giving you problems (for example: `/library/mod_seq_df/instrument`. The current Pandas version is 1.5.2, so that may be my problem. I can't remember if HDFView supports variable length strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more investigation, I have some good news. I also found lots of challenges in the different HDF5 APIs.

First the good news. I can access the data in your file using h5py (a Python package). So, your HDF5 file appears to be fine. While the problems with HDFView are a headache, your errors are not caused by data corruption (or problems with compression filters).

This is what I have determined:

1. Although the groups are named `something_df` and have some
   attributes that look like they "could be" Pandas attributes, this
   file was not created by Pandas. On closer inspection, several Pandas
   attributes you would expect to find are missing.
2. I opened with PyTables (the underlying HDF5 technology for Pandas), and got an error accessing Groups due to an attribute named `is_pd_dataframe` that is saved as an 8-bit Enum (Boolean). Apparently PyTables doesn't support that datatype.
3. When I used PyTables to read a dataset of string values, I get this error: `variable length strings are not supported yet`. This is consistent with the Pandas error message in my earlier comment, and further confirmation the file probably wasn't created by Pandas.
4. I don't know if items 2 or 3 are related to your HDFView and Java problems. I can open and view these attributes on each group's Object Attribute Info tab. (As I understand, HDFView is built with Java - so those 2 problems are consistent.)

I included my Python code (below) that extracts some data. (I know you want to work in Java, but this confirms the data is accessible.) At this point I suggest 2 paths: 1) adding HDF5/Java tags to your SO question to see if the Java community has an answer, and/or 2) contact **The HDF Group** about HDFView problems (you can post a question on their forum at: https://forum.hdfgroup.org/).

**Python/h5py solution:**

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('predict.speclib.hdf','r') as h5f:           
    # read group attributes:
    grp = h5f['/library/mod_seq_df']
    print(f"is_pd_dataframe attribute value: {grp.attrs['is_pd_dataframe']}")
    print(f"last_updated attribute value: {grp.attrs['last_updated']}")
    print()        
    # read varlength string dataset:
    ds = h5f['/library/mod_seq_df/sequence']
    print(ds.shape, ds.dtype)
    for i in range(0,5):
        print(f'{i}: {ds[i]}')
    for i in range(ds.shape[0]-5,ds.shape[0]):
        print(f'{i}: {ds[i]}')       
    print()        
    # read float32 dataset:
    ds = h5f['/library/fragment_intensity_df/y_z1']
    print(ds.shape, ds.dtype)
    for i in range(0,5):
        print(f'{i}: {ds[i]}')
    for i in range(ds.shape[0]-5,ds.shape[0]):
        print(f'{i}: {ds[i]}')
```

**Output looks like this:**

```
is_pd_dataframe attribute value: True
last_updated attribute value: Sat Dec 31 16:26:42 2022

(21785,) object
0: b'YLQEREQR'
1: b'SMLRWMER'
2: b'FIQERFER'
3: b'ENFRECLR'
4: b'FLRLCHFK'
21780: b'SGSGNETPLALKSGGGGGGSQTPR'
21781: b'AAPLLAALTALLAAAAAGGDAPPGK'
21782: b'STAVPPVPGPGPGPGPGPGPGSTSR'
21783: b'GDPGDVGGPGPPGASGEPGAPGPPGK'
21784: b'GSIFGSGGGGMSGGGGGAGGGGGGSSHR'

(277994,) float32
0: 0.0
1: 0.0649685338139534
2: 0.012746012769639492
3: 0.036795008927583694
4: 0.12544597685337067
277989: 0.10976477712392807
277990: 0.06583086401224136
277991: 0.0935806930065155
277992: 0.08901204913854599
277993: 0.2575165033340454
```

Comment: excellent suggestion(s); I will pursue them and add comments here if and when I have a useful answer...

Answer (score 0):

Some information may help, we used python code, https://github.com/MannLabs/alphabase/blob/main/alphabase/io/hdf.py#L242 and https://github.com/MannLabs/alphabase/blob/main/alphabase/io/hdf.py#L213, to create datasets in the hdf file. Although we call it df in this hdf file, it is still a HDF group object containing pd.Series as HDF datasets and a `is_pd_dataframe` attribute.

A string dataset is a `numpy.ndarray` with `dtype('O')`, and no encoding (e.g. `.encode('ascii')`) is involved. I guess a string value in the string dataset is still 32-bit (unicode) array?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).